# Why do I get "No module name users" when trying to run a newly upgraded Django 1.4 project?

Tags: python, django, apache

I have upgraded my site from Django 1.3.1 to Django 1.4. I have an app called 'users'. I have a URL routing rule for my project as follows:

```
url(r'', include('users.urls', namespace='users', app_name='users')),
```

and a specific user profile routing rule:

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ProfileDetailView.as_view(),
    name='profile'),
```

The users app has an empty **init**.py file. Nevertheless, I receive a template error:

```
Error during template rendering

In template /home/daniel/python_practice/rainbow/django_templates/user_bar.html, error at line 3
No module named users
```

when I use the following template code:

```
<a href="{%url users:profile user.id %}">{{ user.username }}</a>
```

I've been stuck on this problem for some hours. The project is named 'rainbow'. I have tried doing things like modifying the url call parameters to `url rainbow.users:profile ...`. Upon doing so, it tells me that 'rainbow' is not a namespace. It's as if it is recognizing the `users` namespace, but is then looking for a module of some kind and failing.

Does anybody have any insight into this?

---

Edit:

The directory structure is as follows:

```
rainbow
--> rainbow - directory that contains global settings and urls
--> users - the relevant app
    --> __init__.py
    --> ...etc.
--> other apps
--> django_templates (eg. the relevant template would be django_templates/user_bar.html)
```

---

Thanks,

ParagonRG

Comment: What's the directory structure?

Comment: @okm Added basic directory structure to question.

Comment: Can you `import users` in `./manage.py shell`?

Comment: @okm I can indeed. Typing: `$ import users`, followed by `$ users.__file__` outputs the proper location of the `users` app, so all seems good there.

Comment: hmm, Does it only occur on Apache? Which wsgi server do you use?

Comment: @okm I added an answer describing the problem. It was very very simple. I tagged Apache initially because that's where problems were occurring. Over time I narrowed down the problem to being unrelated and, in the end, very simple.

Answer (score 1):

As is so often the case, the problem in my search for an answer was too greatly limiting the scope of my search ad my tests. There were actually two URL config lines with non-existent modules specified. I was simply modifying one at a time to no positive effect.

The lines were:

```
url(r'^join/$', 'rainbow.users.views.register', name='join'),
url(r'^profile/$', 'rainbow.users.views.self_profile',
    name='user_profile_current'),
```

Removing the `rainbow.` from each of these views fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, but when you upgraded you Django to 1.4, have you upgraded your project manage.py ?
[Upgrade of manage.py in django 1.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py)
They talk about path issues you may have now. As okm asked, if you can't start a shell and import user, there's something wrong at the root.

Comment: My current manage.py file is identical to the new Django 1.4 manage.py file suggestion found at that link. I literally just made a new project and analysed the manage.py file it generated to fix mine up.

Comment: I am also able to import users just fine in the shell.